# Material ui card open in new tab on Ctrl+click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material ui card, and I have `<CardActionArea onClick={props.handleClick}>` and when I click on the card I render another component.

Current situation: Ctrl+click acts the same as mouse click.

Desired result: Ctrl+click open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state and React's `onKeyDown` Synthetic Event ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)) to track whether the user is pressing ctrl.

```
 onKeyPress= (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          console.log('Enter key pressed');
          // write your functionality here
        }
}
```

```
  const [ctrlActive, setCtrlActive] = React.useState(false)

  const handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Meta") {
      setCtrlActive(true)
    }
  }
  const handleKeyRelease = e => {
    if (e.key === "Meta") {
      setCtrlActive(false)
    }
  }
  const handleCardClick = async e => {
    if (ctrlActive === true) {
      console.log("new tab")
    }
    setCtrlActive(false)
  }

return (
    <Card
      className={classes.root}
      onKeyUp={handleKeyRelease}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
    >
      <CardActionArea onClick={handleCardClick}>
        ...
        ...
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
```

Code Sandbox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-tab-on-ctrl-key-press-ke1ev